# Hiding ImageJ interface elements

Tags: java, scripting, macros, imagej

I'm working on a project involving enlisting a large number of
relatively unskilled workers to do repetitive image analysis using
[ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/). I've written a set of macros which walk them through the
analysis process, but in order to increase throughput and reduce
errors, I'd like to figure out how to hide as much of the gui/menu
interface as possible.

An optimal solution would show just the image in question and a set of
icons to select the correct macro. To further complicate things, I'm
planning on delivering the applet and image to be analyzed through a
website (though my understanding is that this shouldn't change too
much).

I've searched a fair bit and can't seem to find an example of how to
do this interface simplification. If anyone can point me in the right
direction I'd be quite grateful. I'm open to any suggestion that works, though since my Java is a bit rusty, a macro/script/configuration solution might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the excellent Action Bar Plugin:

http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=plugin:utilities:action_bar:start